# How to derive "loading" from useSWR between fetches without revalidation?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I was asked a question regarding SWRs "loading" state:

> How do you create a loading state from SWR between different URL fetches?

[Their docs](https://swr.vercel.app/getting-started#quick-start) make it appear straight forward:

```
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/user/${id}`, fetcher)
  const isLoading = !error && !data;
```

However, this logic seems to fail after the first render of the hook/component.  On the first render data is `undefined`.  Then loads and data becomes a value to consume in the UI.

Let's say I change the `id` via the UI and want to show loading indicator.  Because `data` is no longer `undefined`, the same logic fails.

There is an additional item returned `isValidating`.  So I updated my logic:

```
const isLoading = (!data && !error) || isValidating
```

However, this could be true when:

> there's a request or revalidation loading.

So in theory something else causes my component to rerender. This could inadvertently cause a "revalidation" and trigger loading state gets shown.  This could break the UI temporarily, by accident.

So how do you derive "loading" between URL changes without revalidation?  I am trying to replicate how graphQL Apollo Client returns `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Let's say I change the `id` via the UI and want to show loading indicator. Because `data` is no longer `undefined`, the same logic fails.

`data` will be `undefined` again when you change the key (`id`), if it doesn't have a cache value.

Remember that in SWR `{ data } = useSWR(key)` is mentally equivalent to `v = getCache(k)`, where fetcher (validation) just write to the cache and trigger a re-render.

`data` is default to `undefined`, and `isValidating` means if there's an ongoing request.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can derive loading through the use of [middleware](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/middleware). Here's what I use...

`loadingMiddleware.ts`

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Middleware } from 'swr'

const loadingMiddleware: Middleware = (useSWRNext) => (key, fetcher, config) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const extendedFetcher = (...args) => {
    setLoading(true)
    try {
      return fetcher(...args)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const swr = useSWRNext(key, extendedFetcher, config)

  return { ...swr, loading }
}

export default loadingMiddleware
```

`App.tsx`

```
import { SWRConfig } from 'swr'
import loadingMiddleware from './loadingMiddleware'

const App: FC = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ use: [loadingMiddleware] }}>
      ...
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}

export default App
```

### Update (12/13/22)

`swr@v2` is out and provides `isLoading` and `isValidating` properties in the return value of `useSWR`.

Here's the difference between the two according to the `swr` [docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/understanding#combining-with-isloading-and-isvalidating-for-better-ux).

- `isValidating` becomes true whenever there is an ongoing request whether the data is loaded or not.
- `isLoading` becomes true when there is an ongoing request and data is not loaded yet.

Comment: By "loaded," do they mean that there is a cached version of the data?

Comment: Yes. In other words, the `data` property returned by `useSWR` is hydrated. They also state "Fallback data and previous data are not considered "loaded data," so when you use fallback data or enable the keepPreviousData option, you might have data to display."